# Woocommerce posts and products links works only once and then get 404 error

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, permalinks, htaccess, 404-error

Permalink to products and post of my website getting 404 error. after saving the permalink type in Setting -> Permalink page they will work correctly. But if I refresh the links they get 404 error again. Actually the links work only once.

this is my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^.*-(\d+)/$ securityl/index\.php?id=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^.*-y(\d+)/$ securityl/index\.php?cat=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^.*(website[a-z]+map\.xml)$  websiteguide/$1 [L]

RewriteBase /
</IfModule>
```

I have changed the theme to store front and it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that some php code changes the content of `.htaccess` file. The php folder was in a directory named 'securityl'. I've been removed that directory but whenever the website was refreshing the directory and also the php files inside it was recreating. In the end I discovered that some code in `wp-include/load.php` is creating the directory and I re-downloaded the wordpress and replaced the clean wp-include, then the problem solved and there was no code for creating securityl folder! . I don't know how and why the contents of that files were changed.